# Reproducible: after upgrade Gradle i.c.m. Android8.0 -- cannot re-install App - error INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS (Binder.java:682/674)

Tags: android

**This post is different than other posts because due to upgrading Gradle and running the app on Android 8.0 the application cannot be re-installed.**

After upgrading 1 of my 1 year old app to Gradle 4.4, I tried to re-install my app for the 101st time to my Samsung S7 Android 8 device. I got this error:

> Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS:
>   Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113.

Re-installing on a Android 7 emulator or Android 7 mobile works like charm. Installing on a Android 8.0 (Nexus5) emulator gave the SAME error!

I have installed the application a number of times on Android 8. Now it was silently removed by/from Android 8 a couple of days ago. Not because of the anti-virus, but to some feature of Android 8.

After clicking on [OK] for uninstall I got this error:

> $ adb shell pm uninstall nl.deholtmans.categorychecklist Unknown
>   failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674)) Error
>   while Installing APK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to sweisgerber.dev: 
Replace this:

```
implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

By:

```
implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the app install correctly when using Emulators?

If yes, maybe uninstall Avast and try again.

Comment: Alas, no effect.

Comment: this may seem like a dumb question, but did you try to Clean/Rebuild your project?

Comment: Of course ;-) Many, many times. BUT ... see my updates of the question in a few minutes.